# Selenium python chromedriver 110 headless=new interrupts pc when switching between tabs

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, headless, google-chrome-headless

When running two tabs via the new --headless=new mode of Chrome, I noticed that every time I switch tabs, my PC loses focus on whatever I'm doing - the tab switching interrupts PC usage, which did not happen before, with the --headless option. For example, when writing something in a text box, I need to refocus/click back into the text box every few seconds (just as the tab switch happens in the headless browser in the background).

The browser I'm using is set up like this:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
userdatadir = "user-data-dir="+absolute_dirpath+"\\assets\\chromeprofilesalesforce"
options.add_argument(userdatadir)
options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Profile 1')
service = Service()
service.creationflags = CREATE_NO_WINDOW
prefs = {
         'profile.default_content_settings.popups': 0,
        }
options.add_experimental_option('prefs',prefs)
options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
options.add_argument('--headless=new')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service = service, options=options)
```

The command that disturbs PC usage by unfocusing:

`driver.switch_to.window(site)`

Did anyone else notice this, is there a way out of this? I wouldn't mind going back to using two windows instead of two tabs, but I would preferably want to keep just one window with two tabs. At first I thought the issue was with me interacting with said site by using send_keys() and/or click() actions, but running just one tab doing all these never interrupted my PC usage. I also tried to find a way to use the old headless mode, but to no avail. The issue is switching between tabs.

Thank you!

EDIT:

I believed I found the culprit, I was calling my other function, that switches the tabs back and forth, via threading - calling it directly seemed to have solved the issue, but it did not. Can it be something with profiles in Chrome, is there a better way to do this?

EDIT2:

Using the --disable-gpu parameter in the webdriver options now seems to have fixed the issue, but it might be intermittent or come up after a while, so will keep this updated. EDIT of EDIT2: Nope, the issue starts again after a couple minutes of the program running. None of this solved the issue of unfocusing other work on PC.

Answer (score 0):

No idea if you're still encountering this bug but I encountered a similar issue when trying to download files using selenium. The solution I found was to actually not use the "--headless=new" and instead just use "-headless". Totally resolved the issue for me.